# How setAttribute works

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problems when trying to change the class from 'fa fa-angle-up' to 'fa fa-angle-down', the command only works if it doesn't work else please check for me, thanks.

```
if(iconSubmenu[0].getAttribute('class') == 'fa fa-angle-down'){
    iconSubmenu[0].setAttribute('class','fa fa-angle-up')
}
else{
    iconSubmenu[0].setAttribute('class','fa fa-angle-down');
}
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
    at HTMLLIElement.showSubmenu.onclick
```

Comment: your error means `iconSubmenu[0]` is undefined. Where do you declare and initialize `iconSubmenu`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].setAttribute("class", "democlass"); 
}
```

```css
.democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<p>Click the button to add a class attribute with the value of "democlass" to the h1 element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is full example of set and get attribute first you have to get value then set it to element which want to change the attribute of it